# What is that wooden path into the beach called?

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns, image-identification

[image: This is what it looks like]

Some might call it just a wooden path or boardwalk, but I was wondering if this structure had a specific name.

Answer (score 5):

As you have said yourself: boardwalk.

> **boardwalk**
>   ˈbɔːdwɔːk/.
>   noun: boardwalk;
>   plural noun: boardwalks.
>   a wooden walkway across sand or marshy ground.
>   **NORTH AMERICAN**
>   **a promenade along a beach or waterfront, typically made of wood**.

(Google)

If you are happy to accept an American use then that is specifically a boardwalk.

[Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/boardwalk) put the meaning relating to the shore first, without any sort of regional caveat:

> *noun*
>   1.
>   a promenade made of wooden boards, usually along a beach or shore.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this article](http://www.familyhandyman.com/garden-structures/garden-paths/how-to-build-a-wooden-boardwalk/view-all) in *The Family Handyman*, the visible portion of a wooden walkway (the generic term for a boardwalk) is the *decking*. (It's normally composed of wooden *slats*.) The decking is supported underneath by a series of *joists*.

So your picture shows the boardwalk's *decking*, and the *slats* of which it is composed.

Comment: But by that reasoning it would make just as much sense to call it "wood".

Comment: @HotLicks The photo shows the _decking_ of a boardwalk, which is composed of _slats_. What is your objection, exactly?